# How to get array values in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on Localization concept in Rails and need to get some of the localization values in HTML pages. So i generated array in controller like below format.,

```
#array use to store all localization values 
@alertMessages = []

#array values...
{:index=>"wakeUp", :value=>"Wake Up"}
{:index=>"tokenExpired", :value=>"Token Expired"}
{:index=>"timeZone", :value=>"Time Zone"}
{:index=>"updating", :value=>"Updating"}
{:index=>"loadMore", :value=>"Load More"} 
#....more
```

In **HTML** pages i want to get localization values like below or some other type,

```
<%= @alertMessages['wakeUp'] %>
```

so, it will display value is '**Wake Up**',

But its not working..
Can any one please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to use a hash for this (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html), which is like an array with named indexes (or keys).

So do this:

```
@alert_messages = {
   wake_up: "Wake Up",
   token_expired: "Token Expired",
   .
   .
   .
}
```

you can also extend your hash this way:

```
@alertMessages[:loadMore] = "Load More"
```

Access it by using:

```
@alert_messages[:loadMore]
```

Also you should check i18n to do Internationalization, which is a more robust and flexible way: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Able to access by using @alertMessages['loadMore']..., without specifying quotes unable to access value

Comment: oh thanks for pointing out the error, i think you can either use "strings" or :symbols.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Hash to store values
@alertMessages = {}

#hashvalues...
alertMessages[:wakeUp] = "Wake Up"
alertMessages[:tokenExpired] = "Token Expired"
alertMessages[:timeZone] = "Time Zone"
alertMessages[:updating] = "Updating"
alertMessages[:loadMore] = "Load More"

#....more
In HTML pages i want to get localization values like below or some other type,

<%= @alertMessages[:wakeUp] %>
so, it will display value is 'Wake Up',
```

And try to use always symbols because [lookup will be fast](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Comment: and you can convert from symbol to string with to_s
and the reverse with to_symbol.

Comment: while trying your method i am getting this error **NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for {}:Hash):**

Comment: where? cause it works in my computer ... Maybe its in other part of your code that is still using alertMessages as an array?

Answer (score 1):

An array doesn't seem really appropriate here but if you still want to use it, proceed ths way:

```
array.find{|el| el[:index] == "wakeUp"}[:value]
```

You should abstract this though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% 
    @alertMessages.each_with_index do |alertMessage, index|
    alertMessage[:value] if index == "wakeUp"
    end 
%>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why we need to run full length of array...?

Comment: yes you are right. then @apneadiving's answer is the best one: `array.find{|el| el[:index] == "wakeUp"}[:value]`